# Android is there a count down timer widget?

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I want to have a count down timer in my app. It's not a problem updating a `TextView` every second, but I want a widget which let the user choose the time of the count down when pressing it before everything starts...

a `TimePicker` is close but not quite as it got the AM/PM addition.

Comment: `It's not a problem updating a TextView every second` please add your code to the question

Comment: It doesn't matter since updating a text view doesn't meet the requirements

Answer (score 0):

If an maximum of 24h is enought for the countdown, than may be you should just set `setIs24HourView(true)`

Comment: What do you mean? What do I define in the xml for this widget?

Comment: its just a flag inside TimePicker. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html#setIs24HourView(java.lang.Boolean)

Comment: It's the closest thing I've seen but it shows as a spinner in the layout.. it could be nice to have a widget that when pressed will open this spinner in a new window or something like that

Comment: Than use the subclass TimePickerDialog https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.html . See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html for useage